# What is the relative importance of the six Darshanas in the practice of different sects today?

Tags: shad-darshana

The Darshanas are listed as

1. Nyaya.
2. Vaisesika.
3. Samkhya.
4. Yoga.
5. Purva Mimamsa
6. Uttara Mimamsa or Vedanta.

Do different sects emphasize some Darshanas more than others?

Comment: Yoga and Uttara Mimamsa undoubtedly still have followers.

Comment: the question and its body ask for separate things!

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee They don't really ask for separate things

Comment: @Ikshvaku EVERY ..BELONG TO.. does not go with whether they have followers or not which the body says.Suppose each has 1 follower. Even then EVERY ORTHIDOX hindu does not belong to six darshanas

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee Alright, you are correct.